# Space between macros in \edef

Tags: spacing, macros

I wonder how to get a space between two macros in an `edef` statement. My goal is to save a file name of the form `FirstName LastName` to a macro, and later use that macro in an `includegraphics` command.

The problem is that everything I tried returns an undesired result.

```
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName \LastName}    ➞ "FirstNameLastName"
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName{} \LastName}  ➞ "FirstName{} LastName"
\edef\PictureName{{\FirstName} \LastName}  ➞ "{FirstName} LastName"
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName\ \LastName}   ➞ "FirstName\ LastName"
```

So either no space is stored in `\PictureName` or additional parentheses or a backslash are stored. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `\edef\PictureName{\FirstName\space\LastName}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you see is the usual [“TeX ignores spaces after control sequences”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/134574), however here it can't be fixed as you would when producing typeset output. In that case, any method that separates the space character from the control sequence (and will produce a space, of course) in the input will work:

```
\FirstName{} \LastName
\FirstName{ }\LastName
{\FirstName} \LastName
\FirstName\ \LastName
\FirstName\space\LastName
\@firstofone{\FirstName} \LastName % assuming the usual definition of \@firstofone
```

however here you are in an expansion-only context, and in this case you need something a space token or something that *expands* to a space token, while separating it from the control sequence. The methods with braces and with control space don't work here because braces don't expand, so they are left untouched by `\edef`'s expansion. They do work when typesetting because in that context they (form a group and) disappear. The control space `\`  also doesn't expand, so `\edef` leaves it alone.

Both Plain and LaTeX define `\def\space{ }`, so you can do:

```
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName\space\LastName}
```

which, in the expansion-only context of `\edef`, will expand `\FirstName` (without even looking at `\space` just yet), and then it will expand `\space` to a space token, and then expand `\LastName`.

The `\@firstofone` method will also work because `\@firstofone` also works by (one) expansion:

```
\edef\PictureName{\@firstofone{\FirstName} \LastName}
```

this will expand `\@firstofone{\FirstName}`, which becomes `\FirstName`, which then expands as well. Then the space token is seen, and then `\LastName` is expanded. See this related question: [Conversion of space characters into space tokens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516101/134574)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of having fun
let's have two assignments, not just one.
You can play the game
by "recycling" `\PictureName`:

E.g.:

```
\def\PictureName{ \LastName}%
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName\PictureName}%
```

Or:

```
\def\PictureName{ }%
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName\PictureName\LastName}%
```

Or:

```
\def\PictureName#1{%
  \edef\PictureName{\FirstName#1\LastName}%
}%
\PictureName{ }%
```

Or:

```
\def\PictureName#1{#1}%
\edef\PictureName{\PictureName{\FirstName} \LastName}%
```

Or:

```
\def\PictureName#1{#1}%
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName\PictureName{ \LastName}}%
```

Or:

```
\def\PictureName#1{#1}%
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName\PictureName{} \LastName}%
```

Or:

```
\def\PictureName#1{#1}%
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName\PictureName{ }\LastName}%
```

Or:

```
\def\PictureName!{}%
\edef\PictureName{\FirstName\PictureName! \LastName}%
```